# Editing anonymized posts

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, anonymous-user

While searching for help on Stack Overflow, I passed by an anonymized post, and I suddenly wondered what would happen if I edited it, as there is no owner anymore, and I still can't edit without peer review.

I clicked the link and was brought to the same page as usual (at least I didn't see anything special in it).

As there was nothing to change, I couldn't test it. But what would have happened? Just curious.

#### EDIT:

I know this case is not likely to happen, but just like that...

Comment: why would there be a difference?

Comment: I didn't know there was a suggested edits review queue. I read the [tour], but this information didn't really affect me, and I didn't pay attention to it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your workflow is exactly the same. You'll make a 'suggested edit' which will be reviewed by users with 2000 or more reputation in the [Suggested Edits Review Queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/).

The only difference is that there is no author anymore who can approve or reject the suggested edit singlehandedly. Sometimes, edits are quickly approved/rejected by the post owner, who gets a notification from the edit, while other posts stay in the queue waiting for regular reviewers.